# What does "one is to do something" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, construction

What does construction *one are to do something* mean. E.g. in this context:

> Imagine, that you are to open an online shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"...are to..."* simply means 'supposed to', 'going to' or 'probably to'.

So...

> Imagine that you are to open an online shop = Imagine that you are supposed to open an online shop

We use such construction to mean the probability in the future. Again, for example...

> Suppose you are to drive a car....

Comment: I partially disagree. I think it can also mean "be going to". "You are to open an online shop" "You are going to open an online shop". It is quite formal in nature.

Comment: True. let me include that as well @JMB